# SQL Comma list in a IN Clause

Tags: sql-server

So built the below function which gets a list eg 1,2,3,4,5 etc

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetID] (@CustID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CustList VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT @CustList = (SELECT Id + ', ' AS [text()] 
                        FROM Customer
                        WHERE Id < @CustID
                        ORDER BY Id 
                        FOR XML PATH('') )      

    RETURN LEFT(@CustList,(LEN(@CustList) -1))
END
```

Then I have a query

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE Id IN (fnGetID(10))
```

My result is nothing. I know my result is coming back as '1,2,3,4' where it should be '1','2','3','4'

Is there anyway I can achieve the correct result?

Comment: Your function doesn't make any sense to me. You reference @AuthorID which is not in the code you posted. And your query, you have a string literal 'fnGetID(10)'. That is not how you call a function. But I suspect your function needs some help here. What is it trying to do? I suspect your main query should be a simple join instead of this oddball function.

Comment: corrected the query,  i am looking to call a function to get a list back for my IN clause.  my list returns '1,2,3,4' which is not good as the select reads it as 1 string instead of four.  usually a select in the IN would be sufficient but in this case it has to be done in the function

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You have a function for some reason that is not at all clear. Then you are trying to use IN to look at a list of values which will never work. Why can't you simply use a JOIN? That is what they are intended for.

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.   I would suggest using a Table-Valued Function to split/parse the delimited string

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I totally agree but they don't need to split this, they are generating it first. This screams of an inner join to me. Or in this simple example a basic "Where Id < 10" would produce the same output.

Comment: @SeanLange After a second read, you are correct.

Comment: Basically... you can't do what you are trying to do. You can't sub in a list represented in a single string into an `IN()` without resorting to dynamic SQL. Plus it doesn't make sense since you can write this whole thing as `SELECT * FROM customer  t1 WHERE id < 10`

Comment: The original sql is complex and I can't share I wrote it like this to show what I need

Comment: @JNevill is right , go for dynamic sql for it to work